# Can we use ionic 4 web component in NativeScript web implementation?

Tags: ionic-framework, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-codesharing, angular-nativescript

Ionic 4 uses web component. Can we use those ionic4 web  component in Nativescript web implementation??? I know that i have to use native script components for android and ios. But here asked for web code sharing where i would like to use ionic 4 web component.. Is it possible?

Comment: You may implement any library web components, there is no restriction as such.

Comment: yes, it is very much possible.